# Подтверждение поступления на транзитный счет из Google Payments

Tags: google-play

Открыл ИП, открыл в Сбербанке расчетный и валютные счета.
Деньги за покупки в приложениях пришли на транзитный счет.
Теперь необходимо в Сбербанк бизнес онлайн *Подтвердить поступления*.

И вот теперь много вопросов:

1. Какой код валютной операции?
2. Откуда брать номер договора?
3. Какие еще документы необходимы?

Много гуглил, и почему-то практически нет инфы об этом. Поэтому хочется совета от человека, который проходит это каждый месяц и точно знает что да как.

Заранее премного благодарен